# Are Fresnel equations valid in conductors?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, conductors, boundary-conditions

The derivation of Fresnel equations assume no surface charge density or current density is present at the interface, hence making the normal and tangential components of D and H continuous, respectively. I understand this is the case for dielectrics, but what about conductors?
After deriving Fresnel coefficients some books (ex: Introduction to Optics by Pedrotti) present the complex permittivity of conductors and then plug this expression in Fresnel coefficients. I would like to understand why this is correct due to the fact that Fresnel coefficients where derived only for the case where sigma = 0 and j = 0 at the interface, in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure which derivation you’re looking at, but (a) the tangential component of $D$ is virtually always continuous (absent a static charge density which simply contributes a static field), and (b) including a current density poses no problem. Take a look at Ampere’s Law (time-harmonic approximation):
$$
\nabla\times H = J + i \omega D 
$$
It’s clear that the free current and displacement current terms both contribute to the curl of H, they just have a relative phase shift:
$$
\nabla\times H = (\sigma + i \omega \epsilon)E
$$
So we can bundle $\sigma$ (the conductivity, not the surface charge density) into $\epsilon$, giving it a complex value, but nothing else about Ampere’s Law changes. Therefore, the same derivation for the Fresnel coefficients applies in the case of a complex $\epsilon$.

Just in case you don’t believe your book, trust that the validity of the Fresnel coefficients for complex-valued $\epsilon$ has been empirically verified countless times over decades. I have used it myself to calculate the transmission spectra of thin metal films, which I used to successfully model my data.

Comment: Yes I have used them myself as well, and the result when using the refractive index of conductors is the expected. Some books dedicate and entire sub-section to oblique incidence in conductors.

Comment: @fraghotmailcom ah, good! Based on your question title I wasn’t sure whether you were simply looking to understand, or whether you doubted the book’s correctness.